# Using Unity JsonUtility.FromJson to create an object from a json with nested values

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

All attempts to use `JsonUtility.FromJson` on a json with nested values fail.

How would you turn the following json into an object without creating a class for every nested value?

```
{
  "Player": {
    "Level": 1
  },
  "Weapons":{
    "BasicWeapon": {
      "Level": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I had the same error, everything is returning null right ? If so, try to use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(yourString)`

Comment: When trying to get `Player.Level` it returns blank not null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [SimplJson](https://github.com/Bunny83/SimpleJSON) Library Like this

JSONNode node = JSON.Parse( jsonString );

string level= node["Player"]["Level"].Value;

Answer (score 1):

there is also another Library that can Handle that :

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/json-net-for-unity-11347